# Combine elements of two arrays in pairs

Tags: c#, arrays, revit-api

I have three arays:

```
string[] comet1 ={comenta1,comenta2,coment3,......This way for all the selected elements};
string[] paramet1 = { long1,long2,lon2,......};
string[] parametr2={ alt1,alt2,alt2,......};

TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:/archivo.txt")

// añadir linea de texto al archivo de texto
for (int i = 0; i < comet1.Length; i++)
{
    tw.WriteLine(comet1[i]);
}

for (int a = 0; a < paramet1.Length; a++ )
{
    tw.WriteLine(paramet1[a]);
}
```

Using that code the data is added to the `txt` file as following:

```
comenta1
comenta2

long1
long2

.....
```

What I want to do is :

```
comenta1/long1
comenta2/long2

......
```

I tried:

```
tw.WriteLine(comet1[i] + "\\" + paramet1[a]);
```

But  that only adds the first line two times!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tw.WriteLine(comet1[i] + "\\" + paramet1[i]);`? You'll only need one loop,assuming all the `string[]` has the same length

Comment: yes¡¡¡¡¡¡ oh my good....thank pikoh, I think that it was too much tired to see it.

Comment: @KURRY, 1/. What are you trying to do ? 2/. What if you have uneven source data? 3/. You start with i have tree array.. but only two are used, i must have miss something. 4/. What if there is a \ in your string ?

Comment: You're welcome @KURRY . Anyway, have a look at InBetween answer, it's a very clean way of achieving the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a one liner using the [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method found in `System.Linq` and [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
tw.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, comet1.Zip(paramet1, (f, s) => $"{f}\\{s}")));
```

Read the documentation of both methods in the provided links to understand exactly what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comet1.Length; i++)
{
    tw.WriteLine(string.Concat(comet1[i], "/", paramet1[i]));
}
```

Comment: Only issue I see is if `paramet1.Length` < `comet1.Length`.  Really your condition should compare `i` to both.

Comment: Why did you decide I downvoted your answer? I have no idea why its downvoted.

Comment: @InBetween I was just asking to make sure if it contains any errors? not to point fingers, I am sorry if it was understood that way :)

Comment: @KURRY Then please mark it as a correct answer for future references.